# Delete from list in a double loop

Tags: python, list, dictionary

`text.txt`

```
Natha Keefe 3.14 Engineering Biotech Chemistry
Crescentia Dow 3.79 Chemistry Physics Mathematics
Randon Bradhust 3.68 Biotech Engineering Chemistry
Dashawn Bosley 3.54 Mathematics Chemistry Biotech
Nicolasa Sumpter 3.82 Engineering Mathematics Biotech
Cressie Gillespie 3.10 Physics Mathematics Engineering
Tawny Crockett 3.01 Chemistry Biotech Physics
Kennon Inverarity 3.50 Mathematics Engineering Chemistry
Halima Brydone 3.72 Chemistry Physics Mathematics
Esther Bratby 2.67 Mathematics Chemistry Biotech
Lorry Bunger 3.79 Engineering Biotech Physics
Fatemah Desavigny 3.00 Physics Mathematics Engineering
Marti Mclaws 3.05 Engineering Chemistry Biotech
Estephanie Phelps 3.21 Chemistry Physics Mathematics
Tommi Peerless 3.85 Engineering Physics Mathematics
Cynthia Hermitton 3.10 Engineering Biotech Chemistry
Cheyla Hankinson 3.82 Engineering Mathematics Biotech
Giovanna Keel 3.25 Physics Mathematics Engineering
Narissa Worthington 3.30 Biotech Chemistry Mathematics
Aundria Guthrie 3.51 Mathematics Chemistry Engineering
Teneil Maclean 3.22 Mathematics Physics Chemistry
Shealynn Melville 3.02 Mathematics Chemistry Physics
Darrah Smyth 3.89 Physics Biotech Engineering
```

```py
with open("test.txt") as open:
    initial_list = [i.split() for i in open.read().splitlines()]

applicants = sorted(initial_list, key= lambda x: -float(x[2])) #by rank

by_deps = {"Biotech": [], "Chemistry": [], "Engineering": [], "Mathematics": [], "Physics": []}

limit = int(input())

for ii in range(3, 6):
    for i in applicants:
        if len(by_deps[i[ii]]) < limit:
            by_deps[i[ii]].append(i)
            initial_list.remove(i)
```

What I want to do:

1. To open a text file and read values
2. To convert in a format I need
3. To sort that list according to item 3, 4, 5 in each list usuing a
   dictionary
4. To delete a sorted item from list

The problem is that i have error **ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list** . In the final I want to have **applicants** parsed to dicionary and initial list should be empty. How can I make it?

P.S.:
This code:

```py
for i in applicants:
    if len(by_deps[i[3]]) < limit:
        by_deps[i[3]].append(i)
        initial_list.remove(i)
    elif len(by_deps[i[4]]) < limit:
        by_deps[i[4]].append(i)
        initial_list.remove(i) 
    elif len(by_deps[i[5]]) < limit:
        by_deps[i[5]].append(i)
        initial_list.remove(i)
```

does what I want. I`m curios is it possible to have a construction with 2 loops for this?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @mkrieger1
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list

Comment: sounds like you have duplicates in your list?

Comment: did you run that through a debugger?

Comment: @njzk2 if I delete a line with .remove - yes. there are dublicates. But with the code here there is a ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list

Comment: you loop 3 times through that `initial_list`. The second time around, `applicants` is empty.

Comment: @njzk2 oh. understood. how can I make a loop to check 3, 4 and 5? I want to use it as indexes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rewrite code a little bit and it works:

```py
with open("applicants.txt") as open:
    applicants = [i.split() for i in open.read().splitlines()]

by_deps = {"Biotech": [], "Chemistry": [], "Engineering": [], "Mathematics": [], "Physics": []}

limit = int(input())

for ii in range(3, 6):
    for i in sorted(applicants, key= lambda x: (-float(x[2]), x[0], x[1])): #by rank and names
        if len(by_deps[i[ii]]) < limit: #by deps in priority
            by_deps[i[ii]].append(i)
            applicants.remove(i)
```

Thanks everyone for help.

Answer (score 1):

The first time through the `for ii` loop you remove `i` from `applicants`. So everything will be removed when you do the next iteration.

You can solve this by reordering the loops.

```
for i in initial_list:
    for ii in range(3, 6):
        deps[i[ii]].append(i)
    applicants.remove(i)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I was close in my thinking but not to the end :)

Comment: acctually it adds now 3 copy of i :((( How can I make to add only one?

Comment: Isn't that why you have the loop `for ii in range(3, 6)`?

Comment: no. 3, 4 and 5 - just indicies for list from which I`d like to add in another list. I need only one copy :)

I check 3rd, 4th and 5th indicies in a list (i) to have a key from dictionary and add to list to this key in dicionary. I need only one copey. I use range() only like a generator to check indicies.

Comment: But you're using each of those as the key to append `i`.

Comment: Update the question, show sample input data and the desired result.

Comment: okey, i did it.

Comment: you didn't show the expected result

Comment: Why are there 3 subjects but only one score? Which subject gets the score?

Comment: it is sorted by rank and subject in 1st priority. After this rank and 2nd priority and for 3rd the same.